# using "read.csv" in a "for loop"

Tags: r, csv, for-loop

I have 300 *.csv file with the same format as below.File names are the same with different index starting from 1 to 300(e.g. myarray.1.csv myarray.2.csv ....myarray.300.csv):

```
     -124.5 -123.5  -122.5  -121.5  -120.5  -119.5  -118.5
31.5    0   0   0   0   0   0   0
32.5    0   0   0   0   0   0   0
33.5    0   0   0   0   0   0   0
34.5    0   0   0   0   0   1.1 5980.4
35.5    0   0   0   0   0   0   41
36.5    0   0   0   0.1 0   0   56
37.5    0   0   0   0   0   2.4 0
38.5    0   0   1   0   0.3 0.3 0
39.5    0   0   0   0   4.1 0.1 0
```

header is longitude and first column is latitude and other arrays are correspondent values.

I want to use "for-loop" and "write.csv" to read them one by one and convert them to a matrix in a way that it discards the header and first column so I have just the values at the end.
I used this command but it seems it doesn't work:

```
setwd("C:/Users/WF")
for ( i in 1:300) {
file_new_name <- myarray
file_new_name <- paste(file_new_name,i,sep=".")
file_new_name <- paste(file_new_name,".csv",sep="")
file_read     <- read.csv(file_new_name,header=TRUE)
}
```

Comment: That's not csv format, because there are no commas.  If that's actually what your files look like, use `read.table` instead.

Comment: Note that you can replace the two paste steps by one call to `sprintf`: `sprintf('file_name%d.csv', i)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A pattern like this works best in my opinion, and is very R-like in style:

```
list_of_files = list.files("c:/User/WF", pattern = '*csv')
list_of_csv = lapply(list_of_files, read.csv)
big_object = do.call('rbind', list_of_csv)
```

I assume here that all the CSV files you want to read are present in the `c:/User/WF`.

You'll have to fill the details yourself, but this should get you started.

Comment: @ Paul Hiemstra; Thanks. It worked. It seems that binding them together is the best way to do what I want.