# R loop perform function on multiple csv files

Tags: r, csv

I have tried to create a for loop that does something for each of 4 csv files similar to this but with more files.

```
dat1<- read.csv("female.csv", header =T)
dat2<- read.csv("male.csv", header =T)

for (i in 1:2) {
  message("Female, Male")
  Temp <- dat[i][(dat[i]$NAME == "Temp"), ]
  Temp <- Temp[complete.cases(Temp)]
  print(mean(Temp$MEAN))
```

However, I get an error:

> Error in Temp$MEAN : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Not sure why this isn't working. Any help would be appreciated for looping through csv files!

Comment: Where is your closing `}` in the for loop?

Comment: `dat[1]` is the first element of `dat`. `dat1` is another object!

Comment: Probably the best way to read in multiple files is by putting them in a list. See the following link for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19501040/using-read-csv-in-a-for-loop

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think the easiest way to do this is with the plyr package:

```
library(plyr)
myFiles <- c("male.csv", "female.csv")
dat <- ldply(myFiles, read.csv)
dat <- dat[complete.cases(dat), ]
mean(dat$MEAN)
```

The way this works is that you first create a vector of file names. Then the ldply() function performs the function read.csv() on the vector of filenames,  and converts the output automatically to a data.frame. Then you do the complete.cases() and mean() in the usual way.

Edit:

But if you want the mean of each file then here is one way of doing it:

```
# create a vector of files
myFiles <- c("male.csv", "female.csv")  

# create a function that properly handles ONLY ONE ELEMENT
readAndCalc <- function(x){            # pass in the filename
   tmp <- read.csv(x)                  # read the single file
   tmp <- tmp[complete.cases(tmp), ]   # complete.cases()
   mean(tmp$MEAN)                      # mean
}

x <- "male.csv"
readAndCalc(x)                         # test with ONE file

sapply(myFiles, readAndCalc)           # run with all your files
```

The way this works is that you first create a vector of filenames, just like before. Then you create a function that processes ONLY ONE file at a time.  Then you can test that the function works using the readAndCalc function you just created.  Finally do it for all your files with the sapply() function. Hope that helps.

Comment: I can see that you're a beginner at R.  I had the same problems at the beginning of learning R too.  This is normal until you start to "think-in-the-R-way". No worries. You'll get the idea soon.

Comment: Thanks, that works, but it seems to combine all of the files. I want to get a separate output for each of the files. That is why I thought of looping through them.