# Use one function for multiple datasets in R

Tags: r, function

I generated a function like this to check one variable of a dataset 'a':

```
d <- function(x)
{
  a <- sort(levels(as.factor(x)),decreasing=T)[1:3]
  for (i in 1:length(a))
  {
    if (any(table(x[i])==a[i])<600)
    {
      returnlist <- paste(" Month(s) having less data is/are ", x[i])
      return(returnlist)
    }
    else {
      return(print(" All the recent three months have good enough data "))
         }
  }
}

d(a$YEARMONTH)
```

Now I have three more datasets to be checked.
How can I write a function that takes all the 4 datasets at once and give their respective results? Do I have to use these 4 datasets as arguments? 
Also suggest me how to write the return statements giving heading as respective dataset name and below that I need the results of that dataset.

My variable that I passed into the function looks like this:

```
Apr-2014 
Apr-2015
Apr-2016
Aug-2013
Aug-2014
Aug-2015
Dec-2013
Dec-2014 
Dec-2015 
Feb-2014....
```

These months are the months in which responders have taken the surveys along with the year. So there are many responders in each month.

```
@Frank..Thank you for the above lapply function. It worked but I am getting only the first record of each dataset. 
My output is looking like this for now-
1  Month(s) having less data is/are  201604
2  Month(s) having less data is/are  201604
3  Month(s) having less data is/are  201604
4  Month(s) having less data is/are  201604

  For example: If my a , b,c,d datasets have yearmonth values as-

A$yearmonth
201604 201603 201602
34  652 643

B$yearmonth

201604 201603 201602
678 78  98

C$yearmonth
201604 201603 201602
675 897 678

D$yearmonth
201604 201603 201602
566 788 90

So here my function should give output for counts<600 of each dataset.
A$yearmonth
2016
34
B$yeamonth
201603 201602
78             98
D$yearmonth
201602
90

I don’t think my function is checking all the three values of ‘a’ of each argument. How should it be solved?
And also how should I get the counts also to be displayed in the output? How can I get argument name in the return statement so that I can relate my output to that dataset?
```

Comment: Put the data sets in a list and use `lapply()`

Comment: Can you provide a sample data set?

Comment: @Technophobe01: I just added how my argument looks like..

Comment: if your datasets are files, have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36655417/r-loop-perform-function-on-multiple-csv-files/36655931#36655931

Answer (score 1):

expansion of [Richard Scriven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3063910/richard-scriven)'s comment using your `d` function:

```
lapply(list(A$yearmonth, B$yearmonth, C$yearmonth, D$yearmonth), d)
```

going further, here's a different way to construct the d function to produce the output you have in mind:

```
d <- function(df)
{
  a <- sort(levels(as.factor(df$yearmonth)),decreasing=T)[1:3]
  b <- as.data.frame(table(df[df$yearmonth %in% a,]))
  c <- b[b$Freq < 600,]$Var1
  if(length(c)>0){
    print(paste("Month(s) having less data is/are", paste(c$Var1, collapse=', ')))
  else {
    print(" All the recent three months have good enough data ")
  }
}

lapply(list(A, B, C, D), d)
```

Comment: Thank you for the above lapply function. I added few more queries to my question. could you please look into it?

Comment: could you paste some example output of one your your data frames and the result of str(A)? if i understand correctly, A$yearmonth is a six element integer vector where the first three elements represent yearmonths, and the next three elements represent counts. that's bad. instead, the yearmonth column should contain yearmonths, and there should be another column for counts. this would make your task vastly easier, e.g., `A[A$count < 600,]$yearmonth` would then give you all of the yearmonths where the count was < 600.

Comment: there are nearly 50k records. The yearmonth column denotes yr and month. So if it is 201603 it means yr is 2016 and month is 03 . There are many rseponders in each month. so if I apply table(a$yearmonth) this would give me count in each month of that year.  I wanted to check only recent 3 months counts. So I ordered them in decreasing order so that I will get recent 3months in the top. Now I am checking if the count is <600 , say which month of the last 3 months has count less than 3 months.

Answer (score 0):

As @Richard Scriven suggested...

Load your data frames into your workspace and run

```
mydf.list <- lapply(ls(), function(x) if (class(get(x)) == "data.frame")
              get(x)) # create a list of all the data frames in workspace

# apply your function on the list of dataframe, this will return list
my.results <- lapply(mydf.list,d) 

# to get back the results as data frame
data.frame(Reduce(rbind, my.results))
```

Comment: @pinky, you need to update your Q with what you are trying to do. Not to update my answer with your Q. Hence, I am rejecting the edits you posted on my answer.